# Input nao aparece echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Quando dou um echo num value de um input desse arquivo serviceOrderForm.php carregado via ajax, no codigo do browse aparece o  conteudo certinho, porem nao aparece nada impresso no input (em nenhum input com echo). 
Alguem ja passou por isso?
Chamo via Ajax da seguinte forma:

```
$('#form').load('../serviceOrder/serviceOrderForm.php');
```

Porem ele so nao funciona quando é um form para novo cadastro, quando esse mesmo form é chamado pelo botao de editar trazendo os dados do MySQL, os inputs com echos todos funcionam, seja com dados do banco ou imprimindo somente a data..

Sera que o Ajax pode ter algo haver com isso?

Meu código do input:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="dateRegister" id="dateRegister" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" readonly>
```

Meu código Ajax que chama o form (onde exibe os echos no form.php), acionado ao clicar no botao Editar:

```
function insertDataEditForm(_id, _url){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: _url,
    data: {code: _id},
    success: function(data){
      /* Aqui o form exibe os echos*/
      $("#form").html(data);
      console.log('insertDataEditForm');
    }
  });
  return false;
};
```

Meu código Ajax que escolhe a pagina a ser carregada (onde nao exibe os echos no form.php), acionada ao clicar numa categoria do menu.

```
function choosePage(href) {
  console.log(href);
  switch (href) {
    case '../client/clientMain.php':
      area = '../client/client';
      refreshList(area+'List.php');
      searchInputs();
      $('#form').load(area+'Form.php');
      break;
    case '../vehicle/vehicleMain.php':
      area = '../vehicle/vehicle';
      refreshList(area+'List.php');
      searchInputs();
      $('#form').load(area+'Form.php');
      break;
    case '../serviceOrder/serviceOrderMain.php':
      area = '../serviceOrder/serviceOrder';
      refreshList(area+'List.php');
      searchInputs();
      /* Aqui o form nao exibe os echos*/
      $('#form').load(area+'Form.php');
      break;
   }
}
```

Nao tem nada no css que possa estar interferindo, estou usando 99% o css do Bootstrap.
E nao da nenhum erro, nem no console do browser nem nas paginas php.

Resumindo:
Quando chamo um form via Ajax para efetuar um novo cadastro, os echos no value do input nao aparecem, apesar de serem exibido no codigo html do browser.
E quando esse mesmo form é chamado pelo botao de "editar" tudo funciona perfeitamente.

[image: Print do codigo browser]

Comment: Você não tem algum código no javascript que possa estar apagando limpando os campos.

Comment: Não tem nenhuma máscara?

Comment: Já tentou mudar o formato da data no `echo date('Y/m/d')`?

Comment: sobe no JSFiddle ou algum similar, para ficar mais claro

Comment: @Panda Caraca cara, é isso mesmo. Muito obrigado!